# Next JS app builds in the local but failed inside Docker

Tags: docker, webpack, docker-compose, next.js, dockerfile

I am working on a next JS project. I can successfully build that on my local machine. But when I am trying to dockerized the app and build the app inside the docker image I am getting error while building the app. From the error I think that the docker build can not find my static image files. But I can browse the files inside docker image.

**My File Structure**

- assets
- - image files
- components
- - common components
- data
- - some static data
- pages
- public
- styles

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM node:18-alpine3.14

RUN apk update && \
    apk add --no-cache libc6-compat

ENV NEXT_TELEMETRY_DISABLED 1
ENV NODE_ENV production
ENV PORT 3000
EXPOSE 3000

COPY . /app

WORKDIR /app


RUN adduser -u 5678 --disabled-password --gecos "" appuser && chown -R appuser /app
USER appuser


RUN yarn install
RUN yarn build


ENTRYPOINT [ "sh", "entrypoint.sh" ]
```

**entrypoint.sh**

```sh
yarn start
```

***Error During Build***

```
info  - Creating an optimized production build
Failed to compile.

./assets/company/employee/group.jpg
TypeError: Failed to parse URL from /app/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/squoosh/mozjpeg/mozjpeg_node_dec.wasm
    at new Request (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:4816:19)
    at Agent2.fetch2 (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:5544:29)
    at Object.fetch (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:6372:20)
    at fetch (node:internal/bootstrap/pre_execution:199:25)
    at instantiateAsync (/app/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/squoosh/mozjpeg/mozjpeg_node_dec.js:424:28)
    at createWasm (/app/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/squoosh/mozjpeg/mozjpeg_node_dec.js:447:13)
    at /app/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/squoosh/mozjpeg/mozjpeg_node_dec.js:1480:19
    at Object.instantiateEmscriptenWasm (/app/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/squoosh/emscripten-utils.js:15:12)
    at Object.dec (/app/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/squoosh/codecs.js:156:42)
    at Object.decodeBuffer (/app/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/squoosh/impl.js:55:31)

Import trace for requested module:
./pages/ourcompany/OurStory.js

./assets/home/clientFeedBack/image/Ellipse 6-2.jpg
TypeError: Failed to parse URL from /app/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/squoosh/mozjpeg/mozjpeg_node_dec.wasm
    at new Request (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:4816:19)
    at Agent2.fetch2 (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:5544:29)
    at Object.fetch (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:6372:20)
    at fetch (node:internal/bootstrap/pre_execution:199:25)
    at instantiateAsync (/app/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/squoosh/mozjpeg/mozjpeg_node_dec.js:424:28)
    at createWasm (/app/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/squoosh/mozjpeg/mozjpeg_node_dec.js:447:13)
    at /app/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/squoosh/mozjpeg/mozjpeg_node_dec.js:1480:19
    at Object.instantiateEmscriptenWasm (/app/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/squoosh/emscripten-utils.js:15:12)
    at Object.dec (/app/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/squoosh/codecs.js:156:42)
    at Object.decodeBuffer (/app/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/squoosh/impl.js:55:31)

Import trace for requested module:
./components/ClientFeedback.js
./pages/index.js

./assets/home/globalSection/Rectangle 32.jpg
TypeError: Failed to parse URL from /app/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/squoosh/mozjpeg/mozjpeg_node_dec.wasm
    at new Request (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:4816:19)
    at Agent2.fetch2 (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:5544:29)
    at Object.fetch (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:6372:20)
    at fetch (node:internal/bootstrap/pre_execution:199:25)
    at instantiateAsync (/app/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/squoosh/mozjpeg/mozjpeg_node_dec.js:424:28)
    at createWasm (/app/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/squoosh/mozjpeg/mozjpeg_node_dec.js:447:13)
    at /app/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/squoosh/mozjpeg/mozjpeg_node_dec.js:1480:19
    at Object.instantiateEmscriptenWasm (/app/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/squoosh/emscripten-utils.js:15:12)
    at Object.dec (/app/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/squoosh/codecs.js:156:42)
    at Object.decodeBuffer (/app/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/squoosh/impl.js:55:31)

Import trace for requested module:
./pages/GlobalFamily.js

./assets/home/serviceSection/bg.jpg
TypeError: Failed to parse URL from /app/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/squoosh/mozjpeg/mozjpeg_node_dec.wasm
    at new Request (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:4816:19)
    at Agent2.fetch2 (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:5544:29)
    at Object.fetch (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:6372:20)
    at fetch (node:internal/bootstrap/pre_execution:199:25)
    at instantiateAsync (/app/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/squoosh/mozjpeg/mozjpeg_node_dec.js:424:28)
    at createWasm (/app/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/squoosh/mozjpeg/mozjpeg_node_dec.js:447:13)
    at /app/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/squoosh/mozjpeg/mozjpeg_node_dec.js:1480:19
    at Object.instantiateEmscriptenWasm (/app/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/squoosh/emscripten-utils.js:15:12)
    at Object.dec (/app/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/squoosh/codecs.js:156:42)
    at Object.decodeBuffer (/app/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/squoosh/impl.js:55:31)

Import trace for requested module:
./pages/Services.js

./assets/home/serviceViewSection/Rectangle 420.jpg
TypeError: Failed to parse URL from /app/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/squoosh/mozjpeg/mozjpeg_node_dec.wasm
    at new Request (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:4816:19)
    at Agent2.fetch2 (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:5544:29)
    at Object.fetch (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:6372:20)
    at fetch (node:internal/bootstrap/pre_execution:199:25)
    at instantiateAsync (/app/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/squoosh/mozjpeg/mozjpeg_node_dec.js:424:28)
    at createWasm (/app/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/squoosh/mozjpeg/mozjpeg_node_dec.js:447:13)
    at /app/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/squoosh/mozjpeg/mozjpeg_node_dec.js:1480:19
    at Object.instantiateEmscriptenWasm (/app/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/squoosh/emscripten-utils.js:15:12)
    at Object.dec (/app/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/squoosh/codecs.js:156:42)
    at Object.decodeBuffer (/app/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/squoosh/impl.js:55:31)

Import trace for requested module:
./pages/ServiceView.js


> Build failed because of webpack errors
```

I would appreciate the help.

Thanks

Comment: Are you ignoring the .next folder while copying to the docker?

Comment: Yes. I even deleted the local .next folder before dockerize everything.

Comment: Any solution here?

Comment: Yes. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72287806/next-js-app-builds-in-the-local-but-failed-inside-docker/72337151#72337151

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was with the alpine distro. It is a basic linux package that doesn't have any dependency. We need to install some dependency here, specially to handle JPEG images.

**Updated Code:**
***Dockerfile***

```
FROM node:lts-alpine3.14

RUN apk update && \
    apk add --no-cache libc6-compat autoconf automake libtool make tiff jpeg zlib zlib-dev pkgconf nasm file gcc musl-dev

# COPY package.json .

RUN npm install -g npm

ENV NEXT_TELEMETRY_DISABLED 1

ENV NODE_ENV production
ENV PORT 3000
EXPOSE 3000

COPY . /app

WORKDIR /app

RUN adduser -u 5678 --disabled-password --gecos "" appuser && chown -R appuser /app
USER appuser


RUN yarn install
RUN yarn build
ENTRYPOINT [ "sh", "entrypoint.sh" ]
```

Comment: I'm experiencing this on MacOS. Do you know which specific package was needed?

Comment: My problem was with the `jpeg` package.

Comment: Thanks. I was running Node 18. This new answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/72780988/665224 is the better answer for me.

Answer (score 9):

There's an issue importing images in Next 12.1.6 with node 18.

https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/38020

As noted in the comments, `npm i sharp` will likely resolve the issue.